# How to find a t value of a parametric given the X and Y coordinates?

Tags: parametric

(Sorry for the seemingly simple question)

I need to find the t value of a set of parametric equations that corresponds to an (x, y) point on the parametric curve. The parametric curve will always be a circle. I'm given:

- The parametric equation will ALWAYS be a circle
- A cartesian point (x, y)
- The radius of the circle
- The point at which the circle is centered (h, k)
- The parametrics will be in the standard parametric circle form:

  - x(t) = r*cos(t) + h
  - y(t) = r*sin(t) + k

I found the t value corresponding to any point on the circle in quadrants I, II, and IV (and on the axes) easily with `arccos()` and `arcsin()`, but I can't find a way to find it for a point in quadrant III.

This is for a program I'm writing, so the best way I have found is to brute-force find the point by starting with `t` = `pi`, taking the distance formula between (`x(pi)`, `y(pi)`) and the given point (x, y), and iterating on `t` and repeating the distance formula until the distance converges to 0. But, I would like a faster and more direct method, if it exists.

Comment: Do you have access to a function like [$\arctan2(y,x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Yes, I'm using Python and it's part of the math module. Will any values of x and y work, given that they are both between [-1, 1]? What are the limitations of the function? Also, how can I handle circles of different radii?

Comment: I responded to your comment in an answer below, as it got a bit long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, and you talk about both using `arccos()`/`arcsin()` and using an iterative method. Perhaps you're using different strategies depending on the quadrant?

Regardless, you're hitting a common problem in that `arcccos()` and `arcsin()`, each taken separately, don't fully distinguish between all the quadrants. To cover all four quadrants you have to inspect the signs of both values and do a case-by-case treatment. But luckily it's already been done, and it's named `arctan2()`, (or sometimes `atan2()`).

From your equations it looks like it should be as simple as

$$ t = \arctan2( y-k, x-h)$$

You don't need to divide by $r$; `atan2()` handles the 'normalization' for you.

Just be sure to check what range of values your implementation of `atan2()` returns. Usually its $-\pi \lt t \le \pi$, but some use $0 \le t \lt 2\pi$, so if you want something different you would have to adjust the returned value by $2\pi$ for some ranges of returned values.